# How to express the type for a constant?

Tags: c++, c

I have to write some functions with a significant amount of constant in it in a relatively small amount of lines.

*( Don't bother about the way I wrote the formula, it's there to simply express the fact that I have a lot of constants in a small package, this specific example is small too, in practice I have a minimum of 6-7 constants for each function )*

```
T foo( T x )
{
  return k1 * k2 * x - k3;
}
```

Assuming that I'm not interested in declaring the constants as static ( it will also cause problems with the naming convention in my specific case ) `const T k1 = 42;` , I would like to find an alternative .

A viable alternative can be

```
T foo( T x )
{
  return uint32_t{42} * uint32_t{21} * x - uint32_t{33};
}
```

At this point there are 2 main problems:

- I'm not sure if this kind of declaration will create an entire object or just "a number"
- it's a C++ only solution and I'm writing really simple functions that should be C99+ compatible .

Why I would like to do this ?

It's simple, the values for this constants are highly variable, really small values or big values, with really small values there is a significant amount of space wasted, plus this constants are math constants so they will never change and I can optimize this section right from the first release.

There is also another aspect, the default type for numeric constants is a signed integer, I would like to go for an unsigned integer type of arbitrary size.

The problem with the static declaration `const T k1 = 42;` outside the functions, is that different constants have the same name, the value of the constant is different because the function is different, but the name of the constant, mathematically speaking, is the same, so with this solution I'll end up having multiple declarations of the same variable in the same scope. That's why I can't use names or this kind of declarations .

Do you have any idea for writing this in a way that is compatible with both C++ and C ?

Comment: Can you use function-scope statics?

Comment: @dlf I would prefer not to do that. But the more I think about the other options, the more this option "re-surface" .

Comment: Why do you prefer not to, if you don't mind my asking? It seems like the best solution to me: a) you get a name for each constant instead of having "magic numbers" inline, b) the type is stated explictly for the benefit of the reader, and c) you don't have to mix the typenames in with your arithmetic.

Comment: @dlf I will pay a small price that can quickly become a significant variable due to the high number of constants involved: allocation. Plus I don't really need to be "clear" those are math constants and no one should bother about those while using my functions, it's pointless, it would be like investigating the value for `pi`, it's a constant and even if the user could see it, this will change nothing. I will also end up polluting the namespace for the functions.

Comment: For what it's worth, the allocation cost will be incurred no more than once per function. I say "no more than" because odds are good the optimizer will simply inline the values for you anyway if the types are integral.

Comment: @dlf I know that, but this functions are likely to be used into multithreaded or concurrent applications, and this is influencing my view about this.

Comment: That is a legitimate concern if you can't be absolutely certain the values will be inlined.

Comment: @user2485710 This is getting ridiculous.  If the constants have normal numerical types, and are initialized with constant expressions, there are no threading issues involved.  And the constants virtually occupy no space, so there's no point in making them as small as possible; if you're doing integral arithmetic, just use `int`, and if you're doing floating point, `double`.

Comment: @JamesKanze you are likely to be right, the point is that I don't believe in this "no space occupied" case plus I don't see this as threading issue, the point is that if this can be cheaper, I would like it to be cheaper and better. Plus there is no reference in the standard and I'm not sure about the fact that a compiler will really optimize the size and the inlining in the best possible way; the case where the default int is signed vs the unsigned that I would like to have is emblematic, it may be a small detail, but it also can save a good number of cycles in the long run.

Comment: @user2485710 The point is that all arithmetic will be done using promoted types anyway.  By mixing types, all that you are achieving is creating the possibility (very slight) that the compiler will generate extra code to do the promotion (which will take more space).  And of course, you almost certainly don't want unsigned if you are doing arithmetic operations on the values, because unsigned has some very strange properties.  (There are exceptions, of course, when you actually want or need modulo arithmetic.  But they are just that: exceptions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, for integers, you add 'U', 'L', or 'LL' to numbers to make them `unsigned`, `long`, or `long long` in a few combinations

```
a = -1LL;  // long long
b = -1U;   // unsigned
c = -1ULL; // unsigned long long
d = -1LLU; // unsigned long long
e = -1LU;  // unsigned long
f = -1UL;  // unsigned long
```

One other option, in C, is to cast. The compiler, very probably, will do the right thing :)

```
return (uint32)42 - (int64)10;
```

But probably the best option, as pointed by [ouah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119701/ouah) in the comments below, is to use Macros for integer constants ([C99 Standard 7.18.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.4))

```
a = UINT32_C(-1); // -1 of type uint_least32_t
b = INT64_C(42);  // 42 of type int_least64_t
```

Comment: I was considering this, but I quickly discarded this option because it defeats the initial purpose, `long long` doesn't name an exact size, `uint32_t` does.

Comment: it's strange how such a simple thing can be hard to get right. There is no compiler option in `gcc` and `clang` that I can use to say "resize the integers to the smallest type that fits" ?

Comment: @user2485710 in C `UINT32N_C(42)` is an integer constant expression of type `uint32_t`

Comment: @ouah is this a macro from the standard library ? What is it ?

Comment: @ouah: do you have a reference for `UINT32N_C` please?

Comment: @user2485710 a macro from the standard library defined in `stdint.h`

Comment: @pmg C99, 7.18.4 "Macros for integer constants"

Comment: and to correct myself, `UINT32N_C(42)` is of type `uint_least32_t`, not `uint32_t`

Comment: @ouah on my compiler `UINT32_C(42)` works, `UINT32N_C(42)` however, doesn't . It's a typo ?

Comment: @user2485710 typo, it's `UINT32_C` not `UINT32N_C`.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I had never noticed those macros.

Comment: @user2485710 constant literals already take the smallest type that fits (so long as it is at least as big as `int`). Your original post suggests that you wanted to use a specific type, `uint32_t`, for all the constants instead ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I want the smallest type that fits **and** an unsigned integer as a type, the main issue is that the default type for this kind of values is a signed integer, not an unsigned one.

Comment: It's better to write code so that it does not matter what type the constant is in. Also, C and C++ have different rules for which type a constant is.

Comment: I'm confident that we have exhausted all the available options, not necessarily the ones that will fit best in my case, but I think that this is the pool of options that I will consider.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you post a real piece of code where the problem is evident

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong this?

```
inline T foo(T x)
{
    int k1 = 42;
    int k2 = 21;
    int k3 = 33;

    return 1ull * x * k1 * k2 - k3;
}
```

Your comments on the other answer suggest you are unsure about which types to use for the constants.
I don't see what the problem is with just using any type in which that constant is representable.

For the calculation expression, you would need to think about the size and signed-ness of intermediate calculations. In this example I start with `1ull` to use unsigned arithmetic mod `2^64`. If you actually wanted arithmetic mod `2^32` then use `1ul` instead, and so on.

Can you elaborate on what you meant by "space wasted"? It sounds as if you think there is some problem with using 64-bit ints. What sort of "space" are you talking about?

Also, to clarify, the reason you don't want to declare `k1` global is because `k1` has a different value in one function than it does in another function?   (As opposed to it having the same value but you think it should have a different data type for some reason).

Comment: I'm not saying that there is something "wrong" even with default types, they are just not optimized, using `ull` is ok because it gives me an unsigned but it doesn't give me an exact size, there is no way I can assume that an `ull` value is optimized in size. I think that the programmer is still smarter than the average compiler on this, there are no guarantees from the standard that `ull` will be the smallest unsigned integer type that fits my constant, on the contrary, often times the standard reports "a type that **is at least X** in size", which is kind defeating my optimization.

Comment: How you can say that `1ul = 32 bits` or `1ull = 64 bits` ? this is a big error. The standard doesn't guarantee you that .

Comment: `ull` is `unsigned long long` which is at least 64 bits.  The question to consider is *what precision do you want on your calculations*, not "optimized in size" or whatever that means. It's not an "optimization" to use a 32-bit int to multiply 1000000 by 1000000, it's just the wrong answer.